# How to get full height of webpage with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a pseudo lightbox using very little Javascript. I am in the process of creating the translucent black overlay behind the modal but I am having problems stretching the black overlay all the way down the length of the page. The overlay stops at the end of the initial scrollable area. So, if the user scrolls down the page, the page is not completely covered by the overlay. Here is the code that I am using for the overlay:

```
.black-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: 1001;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

It's probably the heigh: 100% that is limiting the page from spanning the whole length of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `position: fixed;` instead.

Comment: Wow amazing. It works. I've never used "fixed" before, only relative and absolute.

Comment: @egidra:  `fixed` is how floating toolbars and such work.  Object stays in same "window" position regardless of where you scroll.

Comment: @Martin B. We use JS fixes for them. :)

Comment: @Martin B.  True, you'll need a workaround for IE 6 if that browser is still important to you.

Comment: I know, just wanted it to be clear :). jQuery uses Javascript for its overlays, too.

Comment: Ah, forget those old-timey IE users. I'll mark it in 3 minutes. I don't have an account here, so it won't let me insta-mark it.